# Device Update for IoT : Couple of queries

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub-device-update

With the help microsoft document I can be able to create the import the changes for image & package base & deploy successfully using simulator. Now I want to deploy the changes Over the Air & verify it if someone already did, please help me out.
Apart from this I have below questions.

1. As per current du.config.json file we have option to provide connection string only. If we want to use certificate, then how we can do that.
2. How to configure the Device Update Agent so that it will support Image update & package update at the same time.
3. When I tried to deploy the actual package I getting below Error
   /**

- @brief ADUC_ERC_UPDATE_CONTENT_HANDLER_PARSE_BAD_FORMAT, ERC Value: 805306472 (0x30000068)
  */
  #define ADUC_ERC_UPDATE_CONTENT_HANDLER_PARSE_BAD_FORMAT MAKE_ADUC_EXTENDEDRESULTCODE_FOR_COMPONENT_ADUC_CONTENT_HANDLER_COMMON(104)

As per logs :
2023-04-06T08:57:53.7129Z 3438[4046] [I] Downloading full target update payload to '/var/lib/adu/downloads/d298a5a7-f216-404e-bebf-9f89e4f968cb/test-1.0.1-aziot-edge-apt-manifest.json' [Download]
2023-04-06T08:57:58.7179Z 3438[4046] [E] Failed to parse specified APT file (/var/lib/adu/downloads/d298a5a7-f216-404e-bebf-9f89e4f968cb/test-1.0.1-aziot-edge-apt-manifest.json). [ParseAptContentFromFile]
2023-04-06T08:57:58.7188Z 3438[4046] [E] An error occurred while parsing APT manifest. Cannot parse specified APT file. [ParseContent]
apt-handler.20230406-085753.log (END)

My test-1.0.1-aziot-edge-apt-manifest.json content
{
"name": "Contoso-Video",
"version": "1.7.8",
"packages": [
{
"name": "azure-iotedge"
}
],
"agentRestartRequired":false
}

Can some one please help to get answer to this questions

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting the answer from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues/453) for the benefit of other community members facing similar issue.

The manifest JSON file schema has several properties which can be found from the link [Importing updates into Device Update for IoT Hub: schema and other information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/import-schema).

One of the properties mentioned in the JSON file is the size of the APT file which is to be declared in bytes. Here are the details of file object property to be declared in the manifest file.

[image]

Passing in the correct file size resolved the issue.